# Workflow for dynamically adding groups for an application

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, customization, facebook-group

I have done some research on how to check whether a user is within a specific group.

good post:

[Restrict my facebook app from other members. But allowed to those who are in a particular group](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7906575/restrict-my-facebook-app-from-other-members-but-allowed-to-those-who-are-in-a-p)

What I need is to allow users to create there own group but use the custom objects and actions I provide.  The custom object and actions describe or give boundaries to the application I am creating in Facebook.  I think this is done in Mafia Wars ( you only play with your friends maybe? ).

Let me know your thoughts!!!

Markus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further review...

I am going about this all wrong.  The platform, Facebook in this case, is designed to segregate users already.  It's called being someone's friend LOL.  If a user logs into my app they will be presented with all of they're friends who have also acquired or accepted the app too.

In other words I need to really read the Facebook API in it's entirety and pay attention.

Markus

Comment: Good job! Helping your self and digging deeper is key to being a successful developer IMO. Plus you learn much more than if someone just posts the answer for you :).